# RFC5545. Calculate event occurrences for RRULE and EXDATE (EXRULE) at same time

Tags: java, calendar, find-occurrences, rfc5545, ical4j

I have to calculate event occurrences. Calculation should be based on recurrent event pattern. Recurrent event pattern is [rfc5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545) based.

I've found [lib-recur](https://github.com/dmfs/lib-recur) library to calculate occurrences. Following description I see they provide calculation using *the instances of a specific instance set (e.g. an rrule, an exrule, a list of rdates or exdates)*. I used calculation for RRULE, it seems works. I need in my logic find correctly all occurrences including into calculation **EXDATE**, **EXRULE**. But seems last exclusions does not support here.
Small code example:

```
import org.dmfs.rfc5545.DateTime;
import org.dmfs.rfc5545.recurrenceset.RecurrenceRuleAdapter;
import org.dmfs.rfc5545.recurrenceset.RecurrenceSet;
import org.dmfs.rfc5545.recurrenceset.RecurrenceSetIterator;
@Test
public void testSpecial() throws InvalidRecurrenceRuleException {
    RecurrenceRule recurrenceRule = new RecurrenceRule("FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTHDAY=23;BYMONTH=5;COUNT=3");
    RecurrenceRuleIterator it = recurrenceRule.iterator(DateTime.nowAndHere());
    int maxInstances = 10; // limit instances for rules that recur forever
    while (it.hasNext() && (!recurrenceRule.isInfinite() || maxInstances-- > 0)) {
        DateTime nextInstance = it.nextDateTime();
        // do something with nextInstance
        System.out.println(nextInstance);
    }
}
```

result:

> 20170714T163325
>
> 20180523T163325
>
> 20190523T163325

Also I know that [google based library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-saddle/google-rfc-2445/20110304) can provide core handlers for RRULES, EXRULE... based on rfc5545 standard. But I've not found how to calculate occurrences here also(including RRULES, EXDATE, EXRULE).

More example but for `google-rfc-2445` library:

```
import com.google.ical.compat.jodatime.LocalDateIterable;
import com.google.ical.compat.jodatime.LocalDateIterator;
import com.google.ical.compat.jodatime.LocalDateIteratorFactory;
import com.google.ical.values.RRule;
@Test
public void test() throws ParseException {
    String sRule = "RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;COUNT=3;INTERVAL=2;BYMONTH=5;BYMONTHDAY=22,23,24,25,26,27,28;BYDAY=MO";
    LocalDateIterable localDateIterable = LocalDateIteratorFactory
            .createLocalDateIterable(sRule, org.joda.time.LocalDate.now(), true);
    LocalDateIterator iterator = localDateIterable.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
}
```

Result:

> 2017-07-14
>
> 2019-05-27
>
> 2021-05-24
>
> 2023-05-22

Please share link to open source library that already has the complex occurrence calculation functionality (calculation should include RRULE, EXDATEs at same time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lib-recur` does support calculating recurrence sets. Though, the interface of this component is not perfect yet (and not very convenient).

Here is a brief example of how it works with one RRULE and one EXRULE:

```
// note: recurrence expansion takes place in a specific time zone
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
// the start of the recurring event
DateTime start = new DateTime(tz, 2017, 5 - 1 /* zero based */, 23, 12, 0, 0);

// parse the RRULE
RecurrenceRule recurrenceRule = new RecurrenceRule("FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTHDAY=23;BYMONTH=5;COUNT=30");
// parse the EXRULE (in this case every 3rd instance of the RRULE)
RecurrenceRule exceptionRule = new RecurrenceRule("FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=3;BYMONTHDAY=23;BYMONTH=5;COUNT=10");

// create an empty RecurrenceSet
// a recurrence set is the set of all actual instance of a recurring event and may consist of multiple instance and excludes sources 
RecurrenceSet recurrenceSet = new RecurrenceSet();
// add the instances of the RRULE
recurrenceSet.addInstances(new RecurrenceRuleAdapter(recurrenceRule));
// exclude the instances of the EXRULE
recurrenceSet.addExceptions(new RecurrenceRuleAdapter(exceptionRule));

RecurrenceSetIterator recurrenceSetIterator = recurrenceSet.iterator(start.getTimeZone(), start.getTimestamp());

int maxInstances = 10; // limit instances for rules that recur forever
// iterate as long as the recurrence set still has instances
while (recurrenceSetIterator.hasNext() && (!recurrenceRule.isInfinite() || maxInstances-- > 0))
{
    // get the next instance of the recurrence set
    DateTime nextInstance = new DateTime(start.getTimeZone(), recurrenceSetIterator.next());
    // do something with nextInstance
    System.out.println(nextInstance);
}
```

You can see that `RecurrenceSet` operates on `long` timestamps, which is far from ideal.

To support `RDATES` and `EXDATES` you can use the `RecurrenceList` adapter. `RecurrenceList` either takes an array of timestamps or a time zone and a string of comma separated date-time or date values (like they are defined for RDATES and EXDATES):

```
// add more RDATES instances 
recurrenceSet.addInstances(new RecurrenceList("20171212T121212,20181212T121212", tz));

// add EXDATES
recurrenceSet.addExceptions(new RecurrenceList("20180523T120000,20190523T120000", tz));
```

Note, in contrast to the `RecurrenceRuleIterator` stuff, this component doesn't have any test coverage yet.

Comment: The bug, mentioned in the first version of this answer, has been fixed.